# Extract data from JSON within Lambda so it's not undefined

Tags: json, lambda

Looking for advice / second opinion.  I'm trying to pass JSON via HTTP API (api gateway) > Lambda.  I'm receiving the data (pic of Cloudwatch), getting undefined when trying to extract values.  The file is being written to S3, but undefined.

I included Lambda code, picture of Cloudwatch logs.  I'm about there :) .   Newbie here...

**Logs**
[image: Logs showing data being retrieved]

**Lambda Code**

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

  var bucketName = process.env.bucketName;
  var folder = process.env.folder;

  var filename = getFileName();
  console.log("Filename:" + filename);

  var raw = JSON.stringify(event.body);
  console.log("raw after stringify:" + raw);

  var results = JSON.parse(raw);
  console.log("results:" + results);

  let firstname = results.firstName;
  console.log("firstName:" + firstname);

  let lastname = results.lastName;
  console.log("lastName:" + lastname);

  let message = results.Message;
  console.log("Message:" + message);

  var content = message + "," + firstname + "," + lastname;
  console.log("content:" + content);

  var keyName = getKeyName(folder, filename);
  var params = { Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: content };

  s3.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err)
    else
      console.log("Successfully saved object to: " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
  });

  function getKeyName(folder, filename) {
    return folder + '/' + filename;
  }

  function getFileName() {
    var _uuid = uuidv4();
    var _date = Date.now();

    return _uuid + "-" + _date;
  }

  function uuidv4() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
      var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
      return v.toString(16);
    });
  }


  var html = '<html><head><title>Prayer received result</title></head>' +
    '<body><h1>Your Prayer has been received!</h1></body></html>';

  //callback(null, res);   - use this when using proxy model
  callback(null, html);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Made the following changes.

//var raw = JSON.stringify(event.body);
//console.log("raw after stringify:" + raw);

var results = JSON.parse(event.body);
console.log("results:" + results);

Hope this helps others.  I'm newer as of this post to Lambda, JSON.